# Cant apt install iputils and net-tools in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm trying to install ping and ifconfig on a docker container. However, when I run this dockerfile, I get the following errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2_2.25-1.2_amd64.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11_1.33-2.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iputils/iputils-ping_20161105-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2-bin_2.25-1.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libpam-cap_2.25-1.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Here is the Dockerfile I used to try and build the image:

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.0.0 
# system libraries RODBC
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    r-cran-rodbc \
    apt-transport-https \
    libssl-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    openssl \
    curl \
    unixodbc \
    gnupg \
    libc6 libc6-dev libc6-dbg
#.
# mssql drivers
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
#RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev mssql-tools
#iptools (ping, ifconfig)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
RUN apt-get install net-tools
```

Are the commands to install iputils-ping & net-tools wrong? If I comment-out the iputils line and only install Net-tools alone, I get a similar error.

Comment: you are missing in  apt-get install net-tools -y, also there is no need to so many apt-get update if you are not adding more sources

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because of this line  `RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list`

You are replacing the entire file with Microsoft sources, the `>` operator replaces the file, you need to append to the file with `>>`, so change the command to `RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list`

The `>>` appends to a file or creates the file if it doesn't exist.
The `>` overwrites the file if it exists or creates it if it doesn't exist.

That is why it cannot find the packages. Sources got deleted by the previous command.

Also, you need to do a apt-get update only one time after adding new sources.

And you are missing a `-y` in the command for installing ping.

Correct command:

```
RUN apt-get install net-tools -y
```

Hope this helps. Comment if any further help needed.

Comment: Thanks for your anwswer. The file was working until I added ```RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping```. I edited the line with ```>>``` instead of ```>```, and added the ```-y``` to net-tools, but I have the same error. It is failing at ```Step 11/23 : RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping```

Comment: Add the iputils-ping in the top apt-get install, before the mssql drivers

Comment: I did it, now it fails at step 5 

```Step 5/23 : RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping```

Error looks like this : 

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2-bin_2.25-1.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libpam-cap_2.25-1.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
```

Comment: with what error it fails when you run the command with -y ? it seems you have trouble connecting to ubuntu archive manager at build time

Comment: ```failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libpam-cap_2.25-1.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? ```

Comment: remember, add the -y do the last line of the dockerfile, also add the >> operator to the line changing the sources, post the error when trying to install iputils alone